# Django External App Installation

Tags: python, django

I didnt find any tutorial on adding an existing app to a Django project.
Can anyone helps me out ?
For example I want to add this http://code.google.com/p/django-friends/ to my existing project.
What are proper steps ?

I tried python setup.py install, it went well but nothing seems to change in my interface.
Im noob of Django so please bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the active and popular projects are well documented and will have install instructions in their README files, have their own wiki pages, or will have docs hosted somewhere like [readthedocs.org](http://www.readthedocs.org). Presence of installation instructions as well as settings and API documentation is usually a good sign of a stable and maintained app.

As others have mentioned- you'll always have to put the app in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings.py file. Sometimes there are additional custom settings which need to be defined, middleware or context processors to be added, and urls which need to be defined. After doing these things as necessary, you'll need to run `manage.py syncdb` and restart your webserver or the dev server.

---

*Update:* for comparison check out [Django Debug Toolbar's README](https://github.com/joymax/django-debug-toolbar/blob/master/README.rst). If you get used to installing some of popular apps by following their docs, you'll get used to how things work and can more easily figure out the smaller apps/projects.

Comment: thank you for the tips and the link. That's quite a number of steps to get an app working. I thought It would be much easier

Comment: couple steps, but really it's only a couple lines of code on your end to get a lot of code integrated!

Comment: syncdb is removed instead use migrate, just in case if anyone encounter that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can just install the django-friends (i.e. download and run `setup.py install` automatically) by running

```
$ sudo pip install django-friends
```

This will install the the python package named `friends` (i.e. a folder `friends` with `__init__.py` in `site-packages` directory on your path.).

To actually install the `django-friends` app in your *django application*, you need to add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` i.e. in `settings.py` file, the `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple should have `friends` as  one of the elements.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'friends',
)
```

NOTE: `pip install apkg` only works if `apkg` is available on PyPI. `django-friends` is indeed [available on PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-friends/). So the easiest way to download it is to use `pip`.

Answer (score 3):

`python setup.py install` install the particular app to your python enviroment and not to you django project. In order to add that app to you django project you have to add it to settings.py `INSTALLED_APPS` or you may have to follow that app installation instructions.

If that app (eg; django-friends) needs to have  one or more database table then you have to run `python manage.py syncdb` in order to create the tables.

Sometimes you have edit you project's urlconf (usually urls.py) and include app's urls in order to reuse app urls.

There might be other things to do in order to complete installation certain django apps so you should read app installation instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest learning and using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). It allows you to create isolated Python environments  for your projects and makes dependency management easier.

One way to check if a package is installed correctly is to try importing it:

```
>>> import friends
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named friends
>>>
```

I got an `ImportError` above because I don't have `django-friends` installed. Otherwise my Python prompt would look like this:

```
>>> import friends
>>>
```

If you have [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) you can run `freeze` subcommand an get a list of all packages installed:

```
$ pip freeze
PIL==1.1.7
cups==1.0
distribute==0.6.14
numpy==1.4.1
protobuf==2.3.0
pygame==1.8.1release
python-apt==0.7.100.1-squeeze1
reportbug==4.12.6
virtualenv==1.4.9
virtualenvwrapper==2.2.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

To sum up; **virtualenv** and **pip** makes it easier to work with packages. And as Praveen pointed out, `django-friends` can be installed from PyPI:

```
$ pip install django-friends
```